# Python: Editing text on personal stdout - doubled text

Tags: python, logging, stdout

I need to save to file same logs as it shows in console so I edit sys.stdout. (Using code from [Redirect stdout to a file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675728/redirect-stdout-to-a-file-in-python))

But the problem shows when i tried to edit text in write function by adding something before it. In result this "[stack]" adds before and after the text variable.

```
import sys

class Logger(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.terminal = sys.stdout
        self.file = open("log.txt", "a")
    def flush(self):
        self.terminal.flush()
        self.file.flush()
    def write(self, text):
        self.terminal.write("[stack]" + text)
        self.file.write(text)
        self.flush();

sys.stdout = Logger()

print "Test log"
print "Another test log"
```

Result:

```
[stack]Test log[stack]
[stack]Another test log[stack]
```

Comment: `print "Test log"` is executed as `write("Test log")` and `write("\n")` - so you get `write("[stack]" + "Test log")` and `write("[stack]" + "\n")`. Try with commas `print "Test", "log"` and you get even more `[stack]` - `[stack]Test[stack] [stack]log[stack]` :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was scratching my head on this one until I figured I should just run it through a debugger. The reason why this happens is that when you use `print`, it will try to write both the body of the text as well as the configured `end`, which by default is a newline.

Each `print` statement therefore results in two separate calls to `Logger.write`, one which is (e.g.) `Test Log` and the second which is `\n`. This results in the output `[stack] Test Log[stack]\n`.

Here is a corrected implementation:

```
import sys


class Logger(object):
    def __init__(self, stream, default_sep=' ', default_end='\n'):
        self.terminal = stream
        self.default_sep = default_sep
        self.default_end = default_end
        self.continuing_same_print = False
        self.file = open("log.txt", "a")

    def flush(self):
        self.terminal.flush()
        self.file.flush()

    def write(self, text):
        if text is self.default_end:
            self.continuing_same_print = False
        elif text is self.default_sep:
            self.continuing_same_print = True

        new_text = text
        if text in {self.default_sep, self.default_end}:
            pass
        elif self.continuing_same_print:
            pass
        else:
            new_text = '[stack]' + new_text

        self.terminal.write(new_text)
        self.file.write(text)
        self.flush()


sys.stdout = Logger(sys.stdout)

print("Test", "log")
print("Another test log")
print()
```

**Output**

```
[stack]Test log
[stack]Another test log
```

**Edit**

Updated implementation to support multiple objects being printed within a print statement.

Comment: try with `print("Test", "log")` and you get `[stack]Test[stack] [stack]log` :) It still need some work.

Comment: @furas Well spotted, I'm on it.

Comment: so ... Good Luck. :)

Comment: @furas I think I've got it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Python3, you can overload builtin `print` to customize the output. Below code gives you expected output:

```
import sys
import builtins

class Logger(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.terminal = sys.stdout
        self.file = open("log.txt", "a")
    def flush(self):
        self.terminal.flush()
        self.file.flush()
    def write(self, text):
        self.terminal.write(text)
        self.file.write(text)
        self.flush();

def myprint(string):
  builtins.print("%s%s" % ("[stack]", string))

print = myprint

sys.stdout = Logger()
```